# How to get quoted text from string in flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, text, double-quotes

I have a string which may contain quoted text, something like this
`String question = 'Vertices of the triangle are "(5,-2),(-1,2)(1,4)"'`
I want to get that quoted text from the string and store it in another string like this.
`String numbers = '(5,-2),(-1,2),(1,4)'`

I have tried finding a solution and I have tried to read the documentation on string but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
final String question = 'Vertices of the triangle are "(5,-2),(-1,2)(1,4)"';
final match = RegExp(r'"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"').firstMatch(question);
print(match?.group(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String question =
      'Vertices of the triangle are "(5,-2),(-1,2)(1,4)"';

  RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'"(.*?)"');
  List<RegExpMatch> matches = regExp.allMatches(question).toList();

  String numbers = matches.map((match) => match.group(1)).join(',');
  print(numbers); // Output: (5,-2),(-1,2),(1,4),(10,10),(15,20),(25,30)
```